# AWS Handling bounces & complaints

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I need to handle bounces & complaints.

I've set up SES to do an event on bounce & complaint which Calls an SES-TOPIC which then is linked to an SNS-Queue.

I'm not sure how this notifies my server or how to hook it up to my server. I just need for AWS to call an endpoint of mine with data or to provide an endpoint with data.

Can anybody help explain what I'm missing here?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: were u able to solve it? can u please share any helpful links

Comment: I ended up solving this particular issue with AWS, even though it wasn't stable (I didn't trust it'd runn correctly 100% of the time) Even though I implemented it, Complaints & bounces were still getting through. I ended up adding recaptcha to each user-based email request and that solved my issue.